# tensor flow input variable error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am creating a tensor flow code and get an error when I try to run with variables.

The base code is

```
import tensor flow as tf
import numpy as np
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
with tf.name_scope("variables"):
    # keep track of how many times the model has been run
    global_step = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.int32, trainable=False, name="global_step")
    # keep track of sum of all outputs over time
    total_output = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.float32, trainable=False, name="total_output")
with tf.name_scope("transformation"):
    # separate input layer
    with tf.name_scope("input"):
        # create input placeholder which takes in a vector
        a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None], name = "input_placeholder_A")
    #separate the middle layer
    with tf.name_scope("middle"):
        b = tf.reduce_prod(a, name = "product_b")
        c = tf.reduce_sum(a, name = "sum_c")
    # separate the output layer
    with tf.name_scope("output"):
        output = tf.add(b,c, name="output")
# separate the update layer and store the variables
with tf.name_scope("update"):
    update_total = total_output.assign(output)
    increment_step = global_step.assign_add(1)
# now create namescope summaries and store these in the summary
with tf.name_scope("summaries"):
    avg = tf.divide(update_total, tf.cast(increment_step, tf.float32), name = "average")
    # create summary for output node
    tf.summary.scalar("output_summary", output)
    tf.summary.scalar("total_summary",update_total)
    tf.summary.scalar("average_summary",avg)
with tf.name_scope("global_ops"):
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    merged_summaries = tf.summary.merge_all()
sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./improved_graph', graph)
sess.run(init)
def run_graph(input_tensor):
    feed_dict = {a: input_tensor}
    _, step, summary = sess.run([output, increment_step, merged_summaries],feed_dict=feed_dict)
    writer.add_summary(summary, global_step=step)
```

when I try to run the above code

```
run_graph([2,8])
```

I get the error

---

> InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call
>   last) InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a
>   value for placeholder tensor
>   'transformation_2/input/input_placeholder_A' with dtype float and
>   shape [?][[Node: transformation_2/input/input_placeholder_A =
>   Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

I do not understand what I am doing wrong in this since the code is all corrected for the version of tensor flow installed.

Comment: start by importing tensorflow instead of tensor flow

Comment: sorry typo it imports tensorflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your placeholder `a` is defined as being of type `float32` but `[5, 8]` contain `int` values.

`run_graph([2., 8.])` or `run_graph(np.array([5, 8], dtype=np.float32))` should work.